# How to use Datatables ajax source with URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I cannot get it to work,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.details').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sAjaxSource": "http://192.168.1.10/some_data",
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sTitle": "#" },
            { "sTitle": "Date" },
            { "sTitle": "Remarks" },
            { "sTitle": "Dr/Cr" },
            { "sTitle": "Amount"}]
    });
});
```

Is it possible for Datatables to use http url?

Tnx.

Comment: Without http, only using ../somedata it works.

Comment: It looks like you are calling a external site. CORS. Exclude `http` if you are calling with in the same application

Answer (score 0):

Solution I used was to create another "page" it works like

```
http://localhost/get_page/www.somesite.com
```

Then server side would get page and return it as a body.